# How can I pass parameters from Shell to Modules through constructors in Silverlight project which using Prism 4.0 for integration

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism-4

I have a main Silverlight Shell project, which calls several Silverlight Module projects.
I need to pass parameters to my module projects through constructors.

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

"Ask and yea shall receive" is the IOC motto :)

Prism uses injection via the *UnityContainer*. When a module is loaded it will resolve any registered *interfaces* specified in the constructor of the module.

Just specify an interface to an object that you have previously registered as a singleton and it will be passed to with any module. Place all your settings/parameters in that singleton.

If you need more information, just ask.

Comment: Iam using MEF, is there any solution using MEF?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from using Unity with MEF. PRISM 4 now includes MEF and the 2 co-exist happily. You need injection to pass parameters to dynamically loaded/created modules.

Answer (score 1):

Register an object with the container.

```
class MyBootStrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        this.Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IMyInterface), new MyInterfaceImpl());
    }
}
```

Now, the module constructor happily receives that object.

```
class ContentModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IMyInterface _myInterfaceImpl;

    public ContentModule(IMyInterface myInterfaceImpl)
    {
        _myInterfaceImpl = myInterfaceImpl;
    }

    #region IModule Members
    //
    #endregion
}
```

Courtesy: TrueBlueAussie